# home/bitnami/apps apps folder not found on AWS Lightsail

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

```
bitnami@ip-23-45-56-230:~$ ls
bitnami_application_password  bitnami_credentials  htdocs  stack
bitnami@ip-23-45-56-230:~$ cd apps
-bash: cd: apps: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is your question? What makes you think that there should be an `apps` directory on the Lightsail instance? Can you point us to some documentation that references it?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. There is no apps folder in the home folder because there is no apps folder under the installation directory (/opt/bitnami). Please review the documentation you are following and ensure it's the Bitnami's official documentation.

Comment: I tried full bitnami django documentation

Comment: Also updated wahi.py file

Comment: But when i type  mkdir  /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/conf.          It shows no such file or directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No apps folder on django lightsail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63680664/no-apps-folder-on-django-lightsail)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you can see that in [this video](https://youtu.be/6p8tEIqvGoo) or in [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-python-application/).

Comment: @JotaMartos gave an answer which was marked as correct in a question that's exactly the same as this one (just with more details) except that his answer doesn't solve the problem either (at least it didn't for me as I report in a comment to the answer).

Answer (score 2):

This might help: [Quick Start Guide Wordpress multisite](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-quick-start-guide-wordpress-multisite)

for example:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/configure_app_domain --domain <DomainName>
```

It used to be:

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress
sudo ./bnconfig --machine_hostname <DomainName>
```

"apps" is no longer existing.