# No apps folder on django lightsail

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

After creating a new lightsail django instance on AWS, I found that the folders /opt/bitnami/apps/ does not exist as referenced in the documentation https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-python-application/. I've created django instances before on AWS and have never encountered this issue.

```
bitnami@ip-172-26-4-185:~$ ls
bitnami_application_password  bitnami_credentials  htdocs  stack
bitnami@ip-172-26-4-185:~$ cd /
bitnami@ip-172-26-4-185:/$ cd opt
bitnami@ip-172-26-4-185:/opt$ cd bitnami
bitnami@ip-172-26-4-185:/opt/bitnami$ cd apps
-bash: cd: apps: No such file or directory
bitnami@ip-172-26-4-185:/opt/bitnami$ ls
apache   bncert-tool          bnsupport-tool  git      nami        properties.ini  stats
apache2  bnsupport            common          gonit    node        python          var
bncert   bnsupport-regex.ini  ctlscript.sh    mariadb  postgresql  scripts
```

Additional info:
16 GB RAM, 4 vCPUs, 320 GB SSD

Django

Virginia, Zone A (us-east-1a)
attached static ip address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

The apps folder doesn't exist anymore in the Django solution. The guide you are following is not maintained by Bitnami and that's why it's not up to date. To create a new project in the new Bitnami Django solution, you will need to run these commands

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/projects/PROJECT
sudo chown $USER /opt/bitnami/projects
django-admin startproject PROJECT /opt/bitnami/projects/PROJECT
cd /opt/bitnami/projects/PROJECT
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py startapp helloworld
python manage.py runserver
```

and access the port 8000 to see that new hello world project.

You can learn more about this in our official documentation

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/start-django-project/

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/

Thanks

Comment: With this answer I get the error, `mkdir: invalid option -- 'P'`. If I remove `-P`, then I get `mkdir: cannot create directory '/opt/bitnami/projects/PROJECT': No such file or directory`.

Comment: sorry, there was a typo in the mkdir command. The -P option should be -p. I just edited the commands

Comment: At 
python manage.py migrate:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Comment: There is also a reference to the apps folder in the the second link (Approach B) . I have tested my installation, and approach B is the recommended approach, but the instructions still include apps folder, which isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through the same problem (the directories aren't created by the blueprint) and asked it in [AWS Developer Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=328791).

The user donleyataws pointed to [Bitnami's documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/get-started/) and the first thing it tells is to create the projects directory and its ownership.

First, create a new folder to store your Django projects, such as the /opt/bitnami/projects directory, and give write permissions for the current system user. Assuming your in bitnami folder (the one with `bitnami_application_password  bitnami_credentials  htdocs  stack`), then run

```
sudo mkdir projects
sudo chown $USER projects
```

[image: Lightsail Django instance]